# Returning html of an element along with the element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have mark up like

```
<div id="div1">
   <div id="div2">
     blah blah
   </div>
</div>
```

If I use $("#div1").html(), it returns the div#div2. But I want to get the complete html. i.e, along with div#div1.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `$("#div1").parent().html()`.

Comment: I think the solution you offer is not valid. Imagine div1's parent contains more than a single div, it would return them all, isn't it?

Comment: duplicates this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html See the solution.

Comment: @loler I tested the outerHTML, it hits the specific div in the selector + children, so this is a targeted approach. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HzX75/

Comment: @DexterHuinda I just said the same. I have not said that it wont help, i've just presented a fact.

Comment: @loler no, you were saying it has the same effect with parent().html() which is not true, because I tested it also.

Comment: @DexterHuinda, you are right only `.parent().html()` will return other children not `.outerHTML`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
$('#div1')[0].outerHTML
```

EDIT:

The same solution but without using jQuery (better performance):

```
document.getElementById('div1').outerHTML
```

Comment: Dexter, that would be a working solution as long as #div1 has not siblings. Add another div, sibling of #div1, and check again

Answer (score 0):

I would say try to select the parent element, or the other way is to do this:

```
var html = $('<div>').append($('#top').clone()).remove().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .parent():

```
$("#div1").parent().html();
```

However this will also get the html for all siblings. You could just wrap div1 in another div... :)

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` returns `innerHTML` you need outerHTML. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html) can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/96u9c/3/

`:)` special need function, now you can use it for any purpose of your own.

`justtext` will get you the only text for parent tag where as `inner` version will get you children text.

Hope it helps `:)`

You could very well add this to your common javascript file in project or customize it and use it as a plugin in your project.

**code**

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() {

    return $(this).clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();

};

jQuery.fn.justtextinner = function() {

    return $(this).clone()
            .children()
            .end()
            .text();

};

alert($('#div1').justtextinner());​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div />").append($("#div1").clone()).html();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WjynX/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple jQuery plugin that would do the job for you, allowing you to use the native `.outerHTML` property when it exists, or polyfill it when it doesn't.

```
(function($) {
  if('outerHTML' in document.createElement('div')) {
    $.fn.outerHtml = function() {
      return this[0].outerHTML;
    }
  }
  else {
    $.fn.outerHtml = function() {
      return $("<div />").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
```

An example is at http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/qUEyp/